# How do I debug iPad iOS5 Javascript error using an iPad running iOS6?

Tags: javascript, ipad, ios5, ios6

A client has notified me that our website is generating an error for iPads running iOS 5 when using Debug Console in Safari. I only have an iPad running iOS 6 which no longer has the debug console, and I don't see any Javascript errors. I also have various PCs and iMacs available to test on if needed. Is there any way I can replicate the iOS5 script error with iOS6 or iMac to try to debug?

Comment: cheap trick: won't hurt to see what IOS6 added over IOS5 on caniuse...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Adobe Edge Inspect](http://html.adobe.com/edge/inspect/)?

Comment: Is that meant to be installed on the iPad? It says device not supported.

Comment: I've used it without any problem, strange you are having issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can [debug on your Mac by following this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html).

Comment: I was going through this link earlier with my iPad iOS6 hooked up to my OSX Mac and couldn't reproduce the iOS5 debug mode error. The link is very relevant though so I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Link seems to be dead.